# JavaScript/JQuery code doesn't work when is in touch with another javascript code in the same file

Tags: javascript, html, css

Somedays ago I asked for help in building a javascript code to make a word appear at random different places of the screen with each mouse click. I now gathered this code (that was functioning on its own) with another javascript code on the same javascript file and it doesn't work anymore... I'm still a newbie at javascript, so I'm having trouble finding the problem.
I really need help on this one, so if someone could help me with this I'd be very grateful!

HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
<!--HERE-->
<header>
<h4>Here is everyw<span>here</span></h4>
<h5>(it depends where you are)</h5>
</header>


<h1 class="here">Here!</h1>


<button>reposition me!</button>
<!--HERE-->

<!--BECOME-->
<div id="container">
<p><span>Become</span>
<br>to come into existence
<br>to come to be
<br>to undergo <span>change</span>
</p>
</div>

<div id="float">

<div class="dot">
<h4 id="become_original">Become</h4>
</div>

</div>

<h2 id="button1">Transform me!</h2>
<!--BECOME-->

<script src="javascript_become.js" type="application/javascript"> </script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: BAUHS93;
src: url(fontes/BAUHS93.TTF);
}

@font-face {
font-family: Amatic;
src: url(fontes/AmaticSC-Regular.ttf);
}

@font-face {
font-family: bb-book;
src: url(fontes/bb-book.otf);
}

@font-face {
font-family: bebas;
src: url(fontes/BEBAS__.TTF);
}

@font-face {
font-family: mod;
src: url(fontes/MOD20.TTF);
}

@font-face {
font-family: monotonia;
src: url(fontes/monotonia.otf);
}

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border: solid 10px #000;
background-color: #EE3E4E;
border: solid 10px #000;
}

h1, h2, h4, h5, p, button {
font-family: Helvetica;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #000;
font-size: 35px;
line-height: 38px;
}

h1 {
color: #FFF;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

/*botao do here*/
button {
position: absolute;
top: 50vh;
left: 50vw;
border: 0px;
background-color: inherit;
}

button:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
/*botao do here*/

.here {
position: absolute;
top: 35%;
left: 45%;
padding: 1%;
}

/* classes dos conjuntos de caracteristicas do become */
.class1 {
font-family: Amatic;
font-size: 90px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: lowercase;
letter-spacing: 25px;
}

.class2 {
font-size: 5px;
font-weight: Regular;
font-family: BAUHS93;
}

.class3 {
font-family: bb-book;
font-size: 20px;
}

.class4 {
font-family: bebas;
font-size: 90px;
font-style:oblique;
}

.class5 {
font-family: mod;
font-size: 125px;
text-decoration: line-through;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.class6 {
font-family: monotonia;
}

/* classes dos conjuntos de caracteristicas do become */

/*circulo*/
.dot {
height: 465px;
width: 465px;
border-radius: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #F5CDFF;
animation-name: cores;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-delay: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
margin-top: -5%;
overflow: hidden;
}
/*circulo*/

#container {
margin: 30% 0 6% 0;
}

#become_original {
font-size: 100px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#float {
animation-name: floating;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

/*botao do become*/
#button1 {
background-color: inherit;
width: 165px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:2%;
padding: 0.5%;
}

#button1:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
/*botao*/

span{color: #FFF;}

/*animações*/

@keyframes cores {
0%   {background-color: #F5CDFF;}
25%  {background-color: #00ADEF;}
50%  {background-color: #EE3E4E;}
100% {background-color:  #F5CDFF;}
}

@keyframes floating {
from { transform: translate(0,  0px); }
65%  { transform: translate(0, 15px); }
to   { transform: translate(0, 0px); }
}

/*animações*/
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
//HERE -THIS IS THE CODE THAT DOENST WORK
var button;
var button1;

button = document.getElementById('button');
$('button').click(function(){
$('.here').css({
top: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
left: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
})
})
});
//HERE 

//BECOME - THIS ONE KEEPS WORKING JUST FINE
//array:
const classes = ["class1", "class2", "class3", "class4", "class5","class6"];

var selectedIndex = 0;

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){

if(++selectedIndex >= classes.length) selectedIndex = 0;

document.getElementById("become_original").className = 
classes[selectedIndex];

});
//BECOME
```

Comment: No, [java and javascript are different languages](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml).

Comment: But is there anything wrong with the javascript overall that disables one of the codes of working properly?

Comment: This doesn't really say why it isn't working now, but the line button = document.getElementById('button') does not do anything here. There is no element with id 'button' and you don't even use the variable anywhere later on.

Comment: The code that doesn't work uses jQuery, while the code that works is plan JS. So are you sure you have included the jQuery lib?

Comment: I did included the jQuery lib, yes and ended up corrected the line button = document.getElementById('button'). It's working now, thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap your code with jquery `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('.here').css({
      top: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
      left: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
    })
  })
});
```

and add jquery lib to the footer of the body.